# Using plotArrays in Dymola to plot the data over different x-axis values

Tags: dymola

I need to draw a graph like this:
[image: graph showing distribution over x-direction with no values in the middle]
I have used plotArrays two times(1.to get curves on the left, 2.to get curves on the right) to get the curves on in two separate plot-windows.

```
plotArrays(x_neg,SOC_neg,legend=names,id=1);
plotArrays(x_pos,SOC_pos,legend=names,id=2);
```

The middle region is empty. If I use single plotArrays function combining these data, the ends will automatically connect with each other which I don't want to do. 
How can I plot it in single command?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple calls to the function `plotArray` with the same `id` and `erase=false`.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question about this. I need, for example, top line in left bottom and right top to belong to the same dataset. That means, they should have the same color, one legend. If I click on any curve, the other half should also be highlighted. How can I do this?

Comment: Using the `plotArray()` function you can specify the `color`-attribute to make them have the same color. This could also be used to make the curves refer to the same legend at least visually while only creating a single legend entry. Highlighting both curves by clicking on any of them will - to my knowledge - not be possible...